# Photos library still taking up space after deleting photos

Tags: photos, storage, macos

tldr: My photos library is 90Gb. I deleted a large chunk of that (deleted it too from Recently Deleted) but the file size is still at 90 GB. I checked the insides through "Show Package Contents" and I found that the "originals" folder still has the photos I supposedly deleted. Why? And how do I reclaim my storage space?

--

So I'm trying to make more space in my Macbook... my Photos Library is at 101GB now (I know, I shouldn't have let it get that large). My solution is to move the library to my external hard drive, and in order to make them easier to find and access, I planned to split the library into individual libraries per year from 2016 to 2021.

Since Photos doesn't have an easier solution for that, I've been copying libraries and then deleting the photos that don't belong (i.e. clearing the Recently Deleted album too). Started by splitting it into two libraries: 2016-2018 and 2019-2021, then splitting those into smaller yearly ones.

The issue though is that the libraries don't seem to get any smaller. From 101GB, splitting into two just turned into two albums worth 90GB. Now I tried splitting the 90Gb 2019-2021 into the three years, but the libraries are at 81, 80 and 89GB. (I had already deleted photos and then deleted from the Recently Deleted).

When I tried to look inside the library via right click > Show Package Contents, the "originals" folder still had pictures I already deleted. Why is that? And how do I get rid of them? I'd just like my storage space back.

On that note, I haven't touched the original photos library in my MacBook's hard drive. But if the same issue sprouts up, how am I supposed to get more storage space--which was the whole reason to begin with?

Read somewhere that it takes time to reclaim the space. But I'm getting worried, it's been more than an hour now... and I don't know if it really takes that long or there's a bigger bug here.

**UPDATE: I left Photos on overnight, and that photo library is still the same size. I'm beginning to think I have to wait the 30 days? I dunno.

--

I'm running an MBP Retina 2015 on MacOS Monterey. Photos v7.0.
(Please don't tell me to get iCloud Library. I can't afford the subscription.)

Comment: Duplicate the library in Finder (on APFS this will not require much space I think). Open Photos and delete from the default library then quit. Hold the Option key as you relaunch, choose the other library and delete within.

Comment: "My solution is to move the library to my external hard drive, and in order to make them easier to find and access, I planned to split the library into individual libraries per year from 2016 to 2021. Since Photos doesn't have an easier solution for that..." Photos Takeout app (on Mac App Store) lets you export the Photos library into folders by year, year/month, albums etc.